# Change app theme during runtime in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to implement different color pallets to style our app, and have Angular use one of them during runtime.

The use case is we have a UI that will be used by different clients, and each likes it to use a different set of colours. So, after the user logs in depending on which company they belong to I'd like Angular to load a different set of colours.

I found a couple of approaches using CSS variables but unfortunately we need to support IE .

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view this blog post [here](https://medium.com/atom-platform/angular-6-dynamic-themes-without-a-library-c21dfb2cb580)

The author explain to use scss in this case and simply inject scss variable at runtime.

For your concern

> I found a couple of approaches using CSS variables but unfortunately
>   we need to support IE

You need to add some polyfill for that